# Dialog(Date) & Spinner(Dropdown) can be consider as a string? How to Store it into database? I try to explain more what i'm facing

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I've create a String for (dialog)date in database, and one String for Spinner(dropdown). and I'm trying to store this two in database. but it seems not working because of these are not String. But in Sqlite, There is no 'Date time'to store.

**From Databasehelper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Person.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Person_Table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "OID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Date";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Description";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (OID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
               Description TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String Date, String Description) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, Date);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, Description);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

After Clicking the Save button. It should store into database. But I kept clicking and it showed "Data Not Inserted". Is (dialog)Date and (spinner)Dropdown can't consider as String? So it wouldn't store into database?

**From JavaPage**

```
Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(
                        Display_date.getText().toString().trim(),
                        e_Description.getText().toString());

                if (isInserted == true)
                    Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

**Here is the (Dialog)Date CODE**

```
 Display_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Donation.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, DataListener,
                        year, month, day);

                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        DataListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                Display_date.setText(date);
            }
        };
```

**Here is the (Spinner) Dropdown CODE**

```
public void dropdown() {

        Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.s_Description);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Beverage", "food"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: show your database creation query and error logs

Comment: If variable have methode toString() it can be converting to String data. It's somthing wrong with your DB. Post your declaration, and log.

Comment: You see JavaPage there has toast, showed Data not inserted. @VivekMishra

Comment: I posted below @StanislavBatura

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do ? insertData method that you posted before had just 2 parameters.But in your whole database class that method has 5 parameters.

Comment: Also add that code to your question not as an answer

Comment: actually I wanted to store the person's name, date, and let them choose the description(dropdown). But it can only store the Edit text which the user typed. but can't store date and dropdown to the database. @VivekMishra sry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table has just 2 columns 1 for id and 2nd for description.You are trying to insert your description in id column and date in description column. Hence it will be giving exception.

To correct it, **create 1 more column** in your database for datetime of String type and then try inserting your data again.

Remember to uninstall your current app before trying again as tables once created can't be updated unless you use that code in `onUpgrade()` method and for onUpgrade() to get called you have to keep version codes.

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot. @Vivek Mishra

Comment: IT WORKS!! After i deleted the app and install again. Now only left the spinner needs to store in database. Thank you~!!

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing with coloumn names. In your `insertData(String Date, String Description)`. In that code you have only one 2 coloumns in your DB. OIB and COL_2. But you are trying to insert data in COL_3 position. So it will be an error. Add one more coloumn COL_3.